# LWN-Simulator Installation in Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, simulator

I have a problem installing Lora simulator in Ubuntu.

https://github.com/UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-Simulator#installation

I have followed all the steps in the repository, however in the penultimate step I get this error

```
daniel@daniel-VirtualBox:~/LoRaDevSim/LWN-Simulator$ make build
-e Building the LWN Simulator
-e Building the User Interface
/bin/sh: 1: statik: not found
make: *** [Makefile:8: build] Error 127
```

I have the "go" installed and the system updated

I tried to uninstall "g0" and reinstall it.

```
sudo mv go /usr/local
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go 
export GOPATH=$HOME/Projects/Proj1 
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

```
git clone https://github.com/UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-S...
cd LWN-Simulator
make install-dep
make build
make run-release
```

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile installs the `statik` command using `go install`:

```
install-dep:
    @go install github.com/rakyll/statik
    @go get -u -d ./...
```

That will install the `statik` binary into whichever directory `go env GOPATH` points at. Typically, that will be `$HOME/go`, which means you need to have `$HOME/go/bin` in your `$PATH`:

```
PATH=$HOME/go/bin:$PATH
```